# After migrating db php returns latin1 charset, but in DB - cp1251

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, phpmyadmin, latin1

I need to transfer my mysql DB from windows server to Ubuntu server.
So i made export in phpmyadmin on win and imported *.sql file in linux.
In linux PMA all looks okay, tables are healthy, no errors, and charter set is (cp1251), russian data in tables looks how it needed.
But when i try to run select in php script there is only "???????" in result, and echo `mysql_client_encoding()` showing that charset is  latin1.
Please, tell me where is latin1 can be seted?
Thanks for help.

UPD: I am using now `mysql_set_charset('cp1251');` after each db connection, but its not an pefect solution. Maybe someone can offer other idea?

Comment: Why is it not perfect solution?

Comment: i think it must be an database solution. its hard to use `mysql_set_charset('cp1251')` in each page. anyway, I'm using `mysql_query('SET NAMES cp1251')` now.